# Dynamically changing the command window title in Matlab

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-deployment

I want to change the title of the the command window in matlab to state the current branch I am working on. 
I know where to find the current branch name. 
I need that every time this file is changed to note on a new branch, the title of the command window will be updated with the new branch name.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The answers to this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924286/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-title-of-the-matlab-command-window?rq=1 -- may help.

Comment: Hi,I need to change it dynamically and not just for the first time. I need to keep track on the changed file and update the command window.

Answer (score 0):

I have this M-file laying around (I think I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141247/matlab-environment-tweaks)). It might suit your needs:

```
function idetitle(Title)
%IDETITLE Set Window title of the Matlab IDE
%
% Examples:
% idetitle('Matlab - Foo model')
% idetitle(sprintf('Matlab - some big model - #%d', feature('getpid')))

    win = appwin();
    if ~isempty(win)
        win.setTitle(Title);
    end
end

function out = appwin()
    %APPWIN Get main application window

    wins = java.awt.Window.getOwnerlessWindows();
    for ii = 1:numel(wins)
        if isa(wins(ii), 'com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLMainFrame')
            out = wins(ii);
            return
        end
    end

    out = [];

end
```

Comment: Hi, but how do I keep track on a specific file and changing the window title?